# Javascript download document using byte array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, blob

I have a webservice that returns JSON object that includes a byte array of document that should be downloaded. How to download that document using javascript?

java code

```
File file = new File(path);
bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

//read file into bytes[]
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
response.put("document", bytesArray);
return response;
```

javascript code

```
var blob = response.document;
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = "tst.pdf";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

The response that I get from javascript is `response = {"document",Object}`.

Comment: the response that i get from javascript is response = {"document",Object}

Comment: Don't try and post your code in a comment. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: hi khelwood done

Comment: what is the content type that you return from your web service `application/json`?

Comment: yes application/json

Comment: Since JSON is textual representation usual way of sending raw bytes is by first encoding them to Base64 String and let client decode them. OR instead of sending all data in JSON you can only send URL of location which wouldn't involve JSON and instead send response containing raw bytes (with proper headers).